# Rails issue: My post will delete but I will keep getting an ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

So when I click the "Delete" link to delete my blog post of my selection, it WILL delete but I will keep getting an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BlogsController#show error that says "Couldn't find blog with 'id'=19. (or whatever that blog's ID is) I do not want this annoying error to show up but I cannot find out what the issue is.

This is what I have for destroy in my blogs_controller.rb file:

```
def destroy
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
 @blog.destroy
 redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
end
```

And this is what I have in my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1><%= @blog.title %></h1>
<p><%= @blog.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Blogs List", blogs_path, class: "back_to" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", blog_path(@blog), data: { confirm: "Are you sure you    want to delete the blog?"}, method: :delete, class: "delete_link"  %>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_blog_path(@blog), class: "edit_link" %>
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: The issue is that you redirect to nonexistent page. Try redirecting to `blogs_path`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same issue. I got rid of (@blogs) after blogs_path, created a new blog post and then tried deleting the blog post ... (which it did when I checked) but the same error will not go away. @blog = Blog.find(params[:id]) is highlighted so I'm assuming there's something wrong with this specific line?

Comment: In `destroy` action you changed the last line to `redirect_to blogs_path` and still get the error? This makes no sense, can you show the `index` action code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
```

You've *just* destroyed the `@blog` object, and yet you wish to redirect to it?

Surely you'd be better with:

```
def destroy
 @blog = Blog.find params[:id]
 @blog.destroy
 redirect_to blogs_path, notice: "Destroyed Blog #{@blog.id}"
end
```